# Why isn't "close" a reserved keyword?

Tags: go, standards

close() seems to be a reserved keyword for channels. Seems a bit strong to make it a built-in, when it could just be a method on a channel, no? Like when creating and closing a file?

I guess the same could be asked for len()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`close` is a function that takes a channel as a parameter. Just like `new` and `make`, they are functions, and you can name local variables or functions like them.

Keywords are language constructs like `struct`, `type`, `if`, `else` ...

Comment: ok that's true, I mixed that up. But why is this a separate "built in" function? Why not make it a method of channels? e.g. for a file pointer created through os.Create() you have to use fp.Close() as well? Wouldn't it be more consistent to have that for channels as well, e.g. channel.Close()?

Comment: channels are native types of Go, like int, uint, string, and others, channels cannot have methods. That's why you find packages like 'bytes' to manipulate []byte, or 'strings' package to manipulate strings. In contrast to os.Create() which returns a struct instance, which can have methods.

Comment: Please don't forget to make your question as answered